# Loop through every element of many arrays

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check the condition for every element in many arrays. I want to optimize it to one loop. Is that possible. I already checked code for array of arrays and collection of arrays, but I keep getting an type-mismatch error.
The code:

```
Private Function RowNo(ByVal text1 As String) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = Columns(2).Find(text1, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        RowNo = f.Row
    Else
        RowNo = 0
    End If
End Function

Q1 = "1."
YtQ1Ar = Array("1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6", "1.7", "1.7.1", "1.7.2", _
"1.7.3", "1.7.4", "1.7.5", "1.7.6", "1.7.7", "1.7.8", "1.7.9", "1.7.10", "1.7.11", "1.7.12", _
"1.7.13", "1.7.14", "1.7.15", "1.7.16", "1.7.17", "1.7.18", "1.7.19", "1.7.20", "1.7.21", "1.7.22", _
"1.7.23", "1.7.24", "1.8", "1.9", "1.10", "1.11", "1.12", "1.13")
NtQ1Ar = Array("1.1")

Dim ArColl As Collection
Set ArColl = New Collection

ArColl.Add YtQ1Ar
ArColl.Add NtQ1Ar
ArColl.Add Q1

Dim xColl As Variant
Dim rColl As Long
Dim X As Long

For X = 1 To ArColl.Count
        xColl = ArColl.Item(X)
        For Each xColl In ArColl
        rColl = RowNo(xColl)
            If rColl = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "'" & xColl & "' was not found!"
            End If
        Next xColl
Next X
```

How is it possible to make a loop through every element of many arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i know so far is a sub which calls itself like:

```
Public ArColl() As Variant 'in Module

Sub ArrayRunner(ParamArray SArray() As Variant)
  Dim holder, runner
  For Each holder In SArray
    If IsArray(holder) Then
      For Each runner In holder
        ArrayRunner runner
      Next
    Else
      If Not IsMissing(holder) Then
        Debug.Print holder 'print every element
        'put all values in one long array
        ArColl(UBound(ArColl)) = holder
        ReDim Preserve ArColl(UBound(ArColl) + 1)
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

also Change

```
Dim ArColl As Collection
Set ArColl = New Collection

ArColl.Add YtQ1Ar
ArColl.Add NtQ1Ar
ArColl.Add Q1

For X = 1 To ArColl.Count
  xColl = ArColl.Item(X)
  For Each xColl In ArColl
    rColl = RowNo(xColl)
    If rColl = 0 Then
      Debug.Print "'" & xColl & "' was not found!"
    End If
  Next xColl
Next X
```

to

```
Redim ArColl(0) 
ArrayRunner(Array(YtQ1Ar, NtQ1Ar, Q1))

For X = 0 To ubound(ArColl) - 1
  If RowNo(ArColl(X)) = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "'" & ArColl(X) & "' was not found!"
  End If
Next X
```